# Background isolation from complementing images

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to isolate a background from multiple images that have something different between each other, that is overlapping the background.
the images I have are individually listed here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/68iJD.jpg
but there is a preview of all 6 of them combined here:
[image]

I wanted to do it in a sequence of images, as of I'm reading some video feed, and by getting the last frames I'm processing them to isolate the background, like this:

```py
import os
import cv2

first = True
bwand = None
for filename in os.listdir('images'):
    curImage = cv2.imread('images/%s' % filename)
    if(first):
        first = False
        bwand = curImage
        continue
    bwand = cv2.bitwise_and(bwand,curImage)
cv2.imwrite("and.png",bwand)
```

From this code, I'm always incrementing my buffer with bitwise operations, but the results I get is not what I'm looking for:
Bitwise and:

[image]

the way of concurrent adding to a buffer its the best approach for me in terms of video filtering and performance, but if I treat it like a list, I can look for the median value like so:

```py
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

sequence = []
for filename in os.listdir('images'):
    curImage = cv2.imread('images/%s' % filename)
    sequence.append(curImage)
imgs = np.asarray(sequence)
median = np.median(imgs, axis=0)
cv2.imwrite("res.png",median)
```

it results me:

[image]

Which is still not perfect, because I'm looking for the median value, if I would look for the mode value the performance would decrease significantly.

Is there an approach for obtaining the result that works as a buffer like the first alternative but outputs me the best result with good performance?

--Edit
As suggested by @Christoph Rackwitz I used OpenCV background subtractor, it works as one of the requested features which is a buffer, but the result is not the most pleasant:

[image]

code:

```py
import os
import cv2

mog = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
for filename in os.listdir('images'):
    curImage = cv2.imread('images/%s' % filename)
    mog.apply(curImage)
x = mog.getBackgroundImage()
cv2.imwrite("res.png",x)
```

Comment: you *could* try a "mode" instead of median. for 6 images that should be cheap enough. `scipy.stats.mode`. -- if you need this on video data, check out the "background segmentation" module of OpenCV

Comment: if I do the median for the images in np.asarray or np.stack, the end result is the same (last image)

Comment: I tried using scipy mode, but it has low performance, my end goal would use bigger images and more than 6, I've tried viewing something of background segmentation, but its quite the opposite of what I want, I don't really got a insight of how can I convert that to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `scipy.stats.mode` takes ages to do its thing, I did the same manually:

- calculate histogram (for every channel of every pixel of every row of every image)
- `argmax` gets mode
- reshape and cast

Still not video speed but oh well. `numba` can probably speed this up.

```py
filenames = ...
assert len(filenames) < 256, "need larger dtype for histogram"
stack = np.array([cv.imread(fname) for fname in filenames])
sheet = stack[0]

hist = np.zeros((sheet.size, 256), dtype=np.uint8)
index = np.arange(sheet.size)

for sheet in stack:
    hist[index, sheet.flat] += 1

result = np.argmax(hist, axis=1).astype(np.uint8).reshape(sheet.shape)
del hist # because it's huge

cv.imshow("result", result); cv.waitKey()
```

[image: result]

And if I didn't use histograms and extensive amounts of memory, but a fixed number of sheets and data access that's cache-friendly, it could likely be even faster.